# Tween.js Easing not working

Tags: javascript, html, createjs, tween.js

I'm trying to create a tween (animation) with ease- I've got no problem with animating the x position of my element, but I try to give it an easing. I write the code in appropriate order as shown in the example code [here](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/TweenJS/classes/Ease.html)

And here is my code:

```
this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).to({x:246.5}, 46, Ease.circOut(1.2)));
```

Odd enough, it's not working. It just gives me a blank page.

When I remove the Ease part like:

```
this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).to({x:246.5}, 46));
```

It works, but only sliding, no easing.

How can I make it work with easing?

Comment: Anything in the browser console? Try cjs.Ease.circOut(1.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the console. Try cjs.Ease.circOut(1.2)